# How to retrieve BLOB content from a case

Tags: attachment, blob

We use salesforce to create different cases and we can attach the docs to a case as well.

Now, i have to retrieve the attached doc from a case using REST API. I have used 
below query

```
"SELECT  Body FROM Attachment " +"WHERE ParentId='"+caseId+"' AND Name='" + filename + "'";
```

The query returns `"/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Attachment/00PJ0000003PoLWMA0/Body"` as output which is path of file. But i am expecting a byte stream to be returned.

What shall i do to get the byte array?

Answer (score 1):

You need a subsequent API call to get the binary content.

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/001D000000INjVe/body -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

[More details here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm).